# Programmaticaly support different screen sizes in admob mediation

Tags: android, width, admob

Until now, I was using only `admob` for ads on my mobile apps. 
Using `SMART_BANNER`, I was able to have full width banner on all screen sizes.

Now, I want to start using mediation but `SMART_BANNER` isn't support by other `ads` network.
How can I do to have full `width` ads without `SMART_BANNER`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SMART_BANNER` was introduced as specifically a feature for AdMob. Most other networks don't have an equivalent full-screen format, and therefore their adapters may not return ads for full-width requests. Until more networks start supporting this ad type, you pretty much have to make a decision on full=width ads vs. Mediation.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your answer. Is there no alternative way to get ads with an adapted with (maybe not always full width) on most of the existing devices? Like measuring screen sizes before showing ads and then calling ads with the most adequate size? Does it mean that if I leave admob for another network, I will always have small ads even if I use tablet?

Comment: Other networks support larger sizes (468x60 and 728x90 type sizes are fairly common). They just don't have a "full-width" capability. There is a way to "roll your own" solution with [custom events](https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/ads/mobile-ads-sdk/mediation/custom-events/banners) where you can basically re-implement other ad network adapters yourself and define what should happen when a full-screen ad is requested, but requires some more work on your end.

Comment: The default behavior of the adapters SHOULD be they check the size of the ad passed to them, see if any of their ad sizes are appropriate for the request (sometimes smart banner is just the standard 320x50 on android phones in portrait, for example), and return an ad if the size is appropriate, otherwise return no fill. But as each 3rd party writes their own adapter, this may not always be the case. Depending on how your use case relates to an adapter's behavior, you may want to roll your own solution anyways for that network.